# MySQL - Deleting records that are older than 4 weeks

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I would like to know how can I delete records from my table, that are older than 4 weeks. I have made this script, but it doesnt seem to work, it just deletes every record from the table. I think that the problem is in wrong syntax of operands.

```
$test = $db->deleteFrom('mtr_position')->where(array('year' < $year || ('year' == $year && 'week' < $week)))->execute();
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I recommend sharing more code

Comment: If it was me, I'd start with raw sql. Then once I had a working query, I'd rewrite that in laravel.

Comment: What does your table schema look like?

Comment: That does not look like valid code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Eloquent and Carbon

Assume that the name of your model is Flight.

To delete the records that are 4 weeks or older.

```
$deletedRows = App\Flight::where('created_at', '<', Carbon::now()->subWeeks(4))->delete();
```

If you want to be more specific about the date by specifying the number of days, use `subDays()` instead of `subWeeks()`.

Read more about [Carbon](https://carbon.nesbot.com/) Addition and Subtraction [here](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-addsub)

Comment: Why on earth would one do date calculation for database record selection in PHP?

Comment: @symcbean I think using Eloquent or Query Builder is the recommended way to perform database operations while using Laravel framework. And I believe it is very useful in case we need to switch to a new database driver in the future, without making any changes in our code.

Comment: that has nothing to do with the question I asked.

Comment: @symcbean It would be really nice if you can suggest a workaround for this in MySQL. Thanks.

Comment: `DELETE FROM atable WHERE adate<NOW()-INTERVAL 28 DAY`